# Query regarding .astype() function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently learning from an online course where I was told that for the `.astype()` function to be used no NaN(null) values must be present. However, while typing a program I was careless and did not check for NaN values and used the `astype()` function. It was an object before and I converted it to boolean, later realizing I had NaN values. However, no errors were raised and upon calling `.info()` on the [panda object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9dbf.png), it returned no null values on the column! Please explain. I have attached images of this behavior.

Comment: Maybe whatever course you watched was talking about converting to int? Pandas [doesn't have support for integer NA](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.astype` can be dangerous. I suggest you only use it for `str` or `'O'` conversions. For numerics there are dedicated [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html?highlight=to_numeric), [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) or [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) methods. Sadly, bools don't have an equivalent method.

`.astype` throws an error if you try to convert something that cannot be converted. Here `NaN` is a float, which cannot fit into an integer container.

```
pd.Series(np.NaN).astype(int)
#ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

But then there's `bool`, and while `.astype` is doing nothing incorrect, it's probably not doing what you want it to do. The issue is that `bool(np.NaN)` is perfectly well defined.

```
bool(np.NaN)
#True
```

So, `.astype` has no issues converting `np.NaN` to `True` when you use it.

```
pd.Series([True, np.NaN, False]).astype(bool)
#0     True
#1     True  <- NaN became True. Did you really want that?
#2    False
#dtype: bool
```

---

Currently, there is no nullable Bool type, so you can't have a bool dtype with `NaN`. You either need to use an object column and `where` after the `.astype`

```
s = pd.Series([True, np.NaN, False])
s.astype(bool).astype('O').where(s.notnull())
#0     True
#1      NaN
#2    False
#dtype: object
```

Or you could try the Int64 dtype

```
s = pd.Series([True, np.NaN, False])
s.astype(bool).astype('Int64').where(s.notnull())
#0      1
#1    NaN
#2      0
#dtype: Int64
```